# Python : Create variables dynamically after checking if it is already present

Tags: python

I have a scenario where i need to create new variables dynamically,

I have three py scripts as below

**const.py**

```
TEST_VARIABLE = 5
```

**library.py**

```
def create_variable(self, key, value):
    #How to check whether the caller has any imports which contains this key as variable ?
    setattr(self, key, value)  
    print("The value is " + getattr(self, key))
```

**test.py**

```
from library import *
import const

class checking:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def execute(self):
        create_variable(self, "hello", "world")
        create_variable(self, "TEST_VARIABLE", "10")
        print(self.hello)
        

c = checking()
c.execute()
```

The flow goes like this,

1. The execute method in checking class will have set of `create_variable` method calls.(No other          logic should be present here only the callers)
2. In `create_variable` implementation, i create a variable using `setattr` function.

Now the problem is, if the caller is like : `create_variable(self, "TEST_VARIABLE", "10")`

before creating that variable in **library.py** i need to check whether its already existing in **const.py** (I cannot `import const.py` in library.py).

Is there a way to access the information using `self` or what is the better way to do it ?

Comment: *I cannot import const.py in library.py* why?

Comment: @ThavasAntonio That's a requirement, as in library.py can be used by many and each of them might not have a const.py. So looking for a generic way

Comment: Why do you need to create variables dynamically?

Comment: @ndc85430 The data for this test.py is coming from a db and this file is created programmatically.  It has its own set of rules which requires dynamic variable creation.

Answer (score 0):

How about to pass already existent attributes (!= variables btw) into `checker` instance?

- `test.py`

```py
from library import *
import const

class checking:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def execute(self):
        create_variable(self, "hello", "world")
        create_variable(self, "TEST_VARIABLE", "10")
        print(self.hello)
        

c = checking()
c.execute()
```

- `const.py`

```py
TEST_VARIABLE = 5
```

- `library.py`

```py
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
from sys import argv


def create_variable(self, key, value):

    finder = ModuleFinder()
    # run same script as original one
    # we expecting that executable file should be test.py
    # (python test.py) in this case argv[0] == test.py
    finder.run_script(argv[0])

    module = None

    # iterating over all python modules allowed to import
    # and search for main module (==executable file ==test.py)
    for name, mod in finder.modules.items():
        if name == '__main__':
            module = mod
            break

    if module:
        # get all module and variable names using in this file
        # skip all python defined attribute names (like __str__)
        # and skip known module names imported by library.py
        imported_module_names = [el for el in module.globalnames.keys() if not el.startswith("__") and el not in ("ModuleFinder", "argv", "create_variable")]
    else:
        # if main module not found (probably it will not happens in real life?)
        imported_module_names = []

    for imported_module_name in imported_module_names:
        try:
            # try to re-import same module
            imported_module = __import__(imported_module_name)
        # if module import failed then name is not a module but variable or function etc. Skip it.  
        except ModuleNotFoundError:
            continue
        # get module attributes (variables)
        attributes = dir(imported_module)

        # skip new attribute creation if it already exists as variable        
        if key in attributes:
            print(f"variable with name {key} already exists")
            return None

    # finally create attribute if all checks passed
    setattr(self, key, value)  
    print("The value is " + getattr(self, key))
```

- Output:

```
The value is world
variable with name TEST_VARIABLE already exists
world
```

Comment: That was my first though but unfortunately the test.py is restricted to change. It must only have the callers and no logics

Comment: @user3164187 Ok, I updated my answer. Now `test.py` and `const.py` unchanged and used as is. `library.py` trying to determine all variables by itself. In other words it re-importing all modules inported in `test.py` and checking variables of it. However not sure if this workaround a good solution for production environment